# How to store the minimum value of three different Series in a new Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, trading

here you are the code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticker = "EURUSD=X"
df = yf.download(ticker, start='2021-1-1', interval='1h')

df['MA30'] = df.Close.rolling(30).mean()
df['MA60'] = df.Close.rolling(60).mean()
df['MA120'] = df.Close.rolling(120).mean()
df['ADX'] = ta.trend.ADXIndicator(df.High, df.Low, df.Close, window=14).adx()
df = df.dropna()
```

How can I get the minimum (of every row) among MA30, MA60 and MA120 and store it in a new column which I may call "ma_min"?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 150)

ticker = "EURUSD=X"
df = yf.download(ticker, start='2021-1-1',interval='1h')
df['MA30'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=30).mean()
df['MA60'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=60).mean()
df['MA120'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=120).mean()


df['ma_min'] = df[['MA30','MA60', 'MA120']].min(axis=1)
print(df.head(400))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_col = df.apply(lambda row: min(row["MA30"], row["MA60"], row["MA120"]), axis=1)

df["mins"] = new_col
```